# strangely slow quicksort for large tables

Tags: c++, quicksort, large-data

I have been doing my homework which is to compare a bunch of sorting algorithms, and I have came across a strange phenomenon. Things have been as expected: insertionsort winning for something like table of 20 ints, otherwise quicksort outperforming heapsort and mergesort. Up to a table of 500,000 ints (stored in memory). For 5,000,000 ints (still stored in memory)  quicksort becomes suddenly worse then heapsort and mergesort. Numbers are always uniformly distributed random, windows virtual memory turned off. Anyone has an idea what could be the cause of that?

```
     void quicksortit(T *tab,int s) {
                   if (s==0 || s==1) return;
                   T tmp;
                   if (s==2) {
                      if (tab[0]>tab[1]) {
                                         tmp=tab[0];
                                         tab[0]=tab[1];
                                         tab[1]=tmp;
                                         }
                      return;
                      }
                   T pivot=tab[s-1];
                   T *f1,*f2;
                   f1=f2=tab;
                   for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
                           if (*f2>pivot)
                              f2++;
                           else {
                                tmp=*f1;
                                *f1=*f2;
                                *f2=tmp;
                                f1++; f2++;
                                }
                   quicksortit(tab,(f1-1)-tab);
                   quicksortit(f1,f2-f1);
     };
```

Comment: I don't know what system you are on but my first guess is you are experiencing a greater number of processor cache misses due to the larger data sets.

Comment: With large arrays, it becomes more important to choose a good pivot value than simply running the algorithm. Try `T pivot=tab[s/2];` and see how that helps

Comment: Do you change your seed value for each run of your code, or are you always using the same initial 5 million size array?

Comment: You say "suddenly worse", but you do not specify how sudden, and how much worse. is it faster at 4999999 and then worse at 5000000, for example? If gradually worse, can you describe or show what the performance curve looks like?

Comment: @jxd: definitely it is reseeded, 2,000,000 qs runs almost half the time of mergesort, 3000,000 they are the same.

Comment: @jxd: more precisely 2,0000,000 (8MB?) is the magical limit. That could be something _Rafael Baptista_ has suggested. However I can't really be sure why the array needs to fit into cache isn't it just enough that cache holds two parts of the array near `f1` and `f2` in my code and `&right` and `&left` in case of the code of user _2501_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You algorithm starts failing when there are many duplicates in the array. You only noticed this at large values because you have been feeding the algorithm random values which have a large span
( I'm assuming you used rand() with: 0 - RAND_MAX ), and that problem only appears with large arrays.

When you try to sort an array of identical numbers( try sorting 100000 identical numbers, the program will crash ) you will first walk through the entire array superfluously swapping elements. Then you split the array into two, but the large array has only been reduced by 1:

```
                    v
quicksortit(tab,(f1-1)-tab);
```

Thus your algorithm becomes O(n^2), and you also consume a very large amount of stack. Searching for a better pivot, will not help you in this case, rather choose a version of quicksort() that doesn't exhibit this flaw.

For example:

```
function quicksort(array)
    if length(array) > 1
        pivot := select middle, or a median of first, last and middle
        left := first index of array
        right := last index of array
        while left <= right
            while array[left] < pivot
                left := left + 1
            while array[right] > pivot
                right := right - 1
            if left <= right
                swap array[left] with array[right]
                left := left + 1
                right := right - 1
        quicksort(array from first index to right)
        quicksort(array from left to last index)
```

Which is a modified version of: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort

Comment: Thank you. That indeed is partially the reason. Originally, numbers were in range 0-9999. Sorting numbers in range of `RAND_MAX` makes things a bit better, namely it raises the limit after which quicksort goes bad.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your array is now bigger than the L3 cache.

Quicksort partitioning operation moves random elements from one end of the array to another. A typical intel L3 cache is like 8MB. With 5M 4-byte elements - your array is 20MB. and you're writing from one end of it to the other.

Cache misses out of L3 go to main memory and can be *much* slower than higher level cache misses.

That is up until now your entire sorting operation was operating completely inside the CPU.

Comment: Thanks, that could be the case. I am going to check this code on a different machine maybe with a different CPU. Mine is i7-2630QM (**6MB** l3 cache shared among 4 cores).

Comment: What still puzzles me though is why quicksort is very different from mergesort. It is quite obvious that heapsort can do very bad with L3 cache constraint - elements are read and written in almost random manner. However in both quicksort and mergesort table is accessed locally. Quick sort needs to maintain to parts of the original table in cache the one near the moving pointer `f1` and the one near `f2`. Mergesort needs to store not only two half arrays near two moving pointers, but also at least a part of the table it is merging to.